# Replace multiple letters maintaining the correct cursor position

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to replace `"abc"` to `"d"` for instance.
Example code replaces only one letter at cursor position but I need to replace multiple letters with the same idea.

```js
$("#text").keypress(function(event) {
  if (event.key === "a") {
    event.preventDefault();
    insertTextAtCursor(this, "b");
  }
});
function insertTextAtCursor(el, text) {
    var val = el.value, endIndex, range;
    if (typeof el.selectionStart != "undefined" && typeof el.selectionEnd != "undefined") {
        endIndex = el.selectionEnd;
        el.value = val.slice(0, el.selectionStart) + text + val.slice(endIndex);
        el.selectionStart = el.selectionEnd = endIndex + text.length;
    } else if (typeof document.selection != "undefined" && typeof document.selection.createRange != "undefined") {
        el.focus();
        range = document.selection.createRange();
        range.collapse(false);
        range.text = text;
        range.select();
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea id="text"></textarea>
```

Any help ?

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to achieve. Replace 'a' how, and when? When it's input? Should the code wait until the entire string 'abc' is matched? Etc.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51825500/replace-text-on-keyup-without-showing-default-value?noredirect=1#comment90605621_51825500 here is what im trying to do actually

Answer (score 0):

Quite simple, the issue here is that we need to be able to read the **input's value**, instead of the **pressed** keys.

```
//All the words that you need to place :)
let wanted = [
    "abc",
  "omg",
  "x"
];

let replaceBy = "Test!";

$("#text").keyup((event) => {
    let old = $("#text").val();

    $("#text").val(old.replace(new RegExp(wanted.join('|'), "gi"), replaceBy));
});
```

There you got a testable *fiddle*, you can even replace **multiple words/characters.**
https://jsfiddle.net/fr24napw/24/

Hope it helps!

Comment: thank you but it is still showing the letter when i type. It shouldn't show me the letter which i press

Comment: for instance when you hold "x", it will show you until you release it, i don't want that, just as i mentioned on the code above

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51825500/replace-text-on-keyup-without-showing-default-value?noredirect=1#comment90605621_51825500 here is what im trying to achieve actually

Comment: I did reply correctly, and on time, if you needed it to be optimized you should have said so, this is not how stackoverflow works.

Comment: Your question is not only completely unclear, but you are actually going against SO . TOS, by repeatedly asking the same question with a different title.