# replace text on keyup without showing default value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm developing a virtual Turkish alphabet keyboard. I'm trying to replace "ed" with "", it works well however it shows "ed" before replacing. How can I get rid off that ? Note that if your computer doesn't have Unicode 6 or more it won't show you the special character which is a skinny X.

```js
$('#text').keyup(function(e) {
  $('#text').css('direction', 'rtl');
  $('#text').css('unicode-bidi', 'bidi-override');
  text2 = $(this).val();
  text2 = text2.replace(/(ed)/g, "");
  $("#text").val(text2);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="text"></textarea>
```

Comment: As a sidenote, this code can be heavily optimized and executed way faster by caching `$('#text')`, using `e`, etc : `const $text = $('#text');
$text.css({'direction':'rtl', 'unicode-bidi':'bidi-override'}).keyup(function(e) {
 $text.val(e.target.value.replace(/(ed)/g, ""));
})` - Also , why set the CSS using jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

Use `input` event instead.

```js
$('#text').on('input', function(e) {
  $('#text').css('direction', 'rtl');
  $('#text').css('unicode-bidi', 'bidi-override');
  text2 = $(this).val();
  text2 = text2.replace(/(ed)/g, "");
  $("#text").val(text2);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="text"></textarea>
```

Comment: It will be very complicated to not display "e" when you type it, and just store it in memory somewhere for future operations.

Comment: @pinug -- How the JS will know that `e` will be followed by a `d` until user actually types it. `e` will show up, and as soon as `d` is typed, it gets converted to the special character.

Comment: Well of course... you can only type one letter at a time. I'm not sure what you're expecting to happen

Comment: did you see the link sir ?

Comment: @pinug -- To be precise on Rory's comment, JavaScript code for event handler will run once per key input. So, it has no way to determine if `e` will be followed by a `d`. That's logically impossible.

Comment: @pinug I think the point is that if you're using this box to store normal alphabetic characters like text,  when you type 'e' the user might intend that it just be an `e` or they might intend to type `d` afterwards. There's no possible way you could know.

Comment: So, if you succed in implementing your solution, the letter "e" can never be typed? Or will it be displayed only after a non-d character is pressed? This is a _lot_ of trouble for not much utility IMO

Comment: user will have a qwerty or azerty keyboard, so im trying to convert it into turkic alphabet, so it can be typed but never be shown

Comment: it is not impossible, i need to change the endIndex or range of event.key but i don't know how to do that (the link i posted above)

Answer (score -1):

Here is something you can build on.

Note I am using keypress and when chars are found in the conversion, I add them

I wonder how you will allow typing of for example eX if you want to allow other chars to be typed than can be converted

```js
var text1 = [],
  text2 = [],
  conversion = {
    "ed": ""
  }
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
  text1.push(String.fromCharCode(e.which))
  var tr = conversion[text1.join("")];
  if (tr) {
    text2.push(tr);
    console.log(text1.join(""), tr)
    $("#text").val(text2.join(""));
    text1 = [];
  }
});
```

```css
#text {
  direction: rtl;
  unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
It is read only. Just start typing<br/>

<textarea id="text" readonly></textarea>
```

Comment: Not only can the "e" still be seen when typed, but the "d" remains in the textarea after the converison too...

Comment: I made it read only now. Just type. You were not supposed to type in the field it is only for output

Comment: But the text is never, ever longer than 2 characters :)

Comment: Please see update. NOTE: _Here is something you can build on_

Comment: Any reason for downvote? The code is not complete - this is not e-lancing